# capturing keypress from a customized keyboard or mouse in Java

Tags: java, input, keylistener, keyevent

I know how to get keypress using `keyListener` and `keyEvent` in java.

Let's say I have a gaming mouse / keyboard which usually have a lot of other button in it (my razer imperator has 3 buttons like that) which is not listed in [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)

Can I create my own class or extend this KeyEvent so I can create my own button (maybe like, VK_special)? If not, why?

Comment: Mouse handling and keyboard handling have considerable differences. I would recommend you to split this question into two.

Comment: It depends mostly on how your keyboard handles those buttons. Are they new key codes, or is it more like a proprietary gaming device, which communicates only with its own drivers ? You might have to be specific on which keyboard you intend of using. Also, yes, splitting in two questions is not a bad idea.